# OleDbCommandBuilder OleDbDataAdapter Problem VB.Net

Tags: database, vb.net, oledb, jet, oledbdataadapter

I have a field in a 2003 access database named first.  I run the data adapter update command, gives me "Syntax error in UPDATE statement." I change the field name to firstName, try the update again, it works.  I already have a bunch of programs using the database and using the field "first", do I really have to rename my field, go back and update all my programs to read from firstName instead of first? I really don't want to go that route if I don't have to.  Any suggestions? Thanks!

(provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0)

*Edit:  I meant to specify, I want the answer to use commandbuilder (but it won't work that way).  Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oledbcommandbuilder breaks when fields are named with the reserved word "first".  Had to write my own SQL

Answer (score 2):

Do this with your commandbuilder object:

```
Dim cmdBuilder As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(oledbAdapter)
cmdBuilder.QuotePrefix = "["
cmdBuilder.QuoteSuffix = "]"
```

This will put brackets around all field names.  I had the same problem with a field named Index and this resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting square brackets around the field name, [first].

Comment: In addition, if you fully specify it with the table name, you avoid the reserved word problem (which is what the issue is here). That is, `MyTable.first`.

Comment: I'm using OleDBCommandBuilder, and it doesn't give you the option to include table names in that way.

Comment: The brackets don't fix it.  I guess I need to write my own SQL insert/update statements or change the field name.  I realize I shouldn't be using reserved words as field names, but I'm surprised Microsoft didn't have the foresight to address this issue.

Comment: The brackets have to go around the field name in your SQL statement.  Have you tried getting the statement that the OleDBCommandBuilder generates and modifying it to include the brackets or the table name?  If you post your code we can probably help you with it.

Comment: MS *did* address the issue, providing more than one workaround for reserved words. The fact that your development tools have too many layers between you and the database and prohibit you from using those workarounds is not the fault of the database engine.

Comment: Which work arounds are you referring to? Your suggestions didn't work.  Thanks for trying though.  By too many layers you mean one, the oledbcommandbuilder.  In this case, it IS the issue of the object (nobody claimed the database engine is at fault other than you).  I'm forced to not use the object and do my own SQL using brackets.  But my question was if there's anyway to get it to work with the command builder.

Comment: Did you try to get the SQL that OleDBCommandBuilder generates and just replace first with [first]?  I seem to remember doing that before.  By the way, your question wasn't if there is anyway to get it to work with command builder.  You were given two answers that would work, then you took mine, copied it to your own answer, and gave yourself the credit.

Comment: Writing my own SQL wasn't the answer I was looking for, sorry. It's just what I'm settling with.  You don't get credit for the concept of writing one's own SQL. I'll be sure to be more specific next question. (I didn't end up pulling the SQL statement from the commandbuilder.  I was already aware of, and tried, brackets.  You didn't "answer" that for me--but thanks for trying)

Comment: My point is that the problem is not with Access/Jet/ACE, but with .NET's database interaction wrappers. It's not like a qualifier for reserved words or fully-qualified fields are exotic Access-only features -- every database engine I can think of has some form of these features, and if your database wrapper abstracts away from you your ability to use them, then it's a problem with the database wrapper.